# Spring ROO change panel width

Tags: spring, panel, roo

I hate to ask this because it must be a very simple answer.  I'm running a Spring ROO-generated application, and I want to change the panel width of the main body.  I plan to add a tile to display on the right side of the panel.  I know that the panel width is calculated by subtracting the menu width from the max wrapper width defined in the standard.css file.  I just can't see where that is done so I can modify it to subtract my new tile's width as well.  I feel like it has to be in panel.tagx, but I am missing it.

Answer (score 0):

I knew if I asked the question, I would figure it out.  I had the tile order wrong.  Panel width is what is left over.